# How do you get amcharts5 to work on nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, amcharts5

How do you setup amcharts5 to work on nuxt?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out answer after posting the question!

On nuxt.config.js add:

```js
build: {
  transpile: ['@amcharts/amcharts5'],
}
```